# How to create interface in Typescript and use as input in Foundry Workshop

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am wondering how I can define a interface in Typecript and use it as input type for a Typescript function.

Just a concrete example: I would like to use a filter list from workshop as input for my function, modify it and return it back.

According to the documentation this should be possible but I am not sure how to do this.

Documentation

```
import { Function, LocalDate } from "@foundry/functions-api";
import { Employee } from "@foundry/ontology-api";

interface EmployeeGraph {
    value: Employee;
    connections: EmployeeGraph[];
}

interface EmployeeFilter {
    maxStartDate?: LocalDate; // Optional using the ? token
    role: string | undefined; // Optional using union of undefined
}

// This Function takes a named custom type as input and outputs a named custom type
@Function()
public myEmployeeSearchAround(root: Employee, filter: EmployeeFilter): EmployeeGraph {
    ...
}

// This Function outputs an anonymous custom type
@Function()
public getAverageAndMedianAge(employees: Employee[]): { average: Double, median: Integer } {
    ...
}
```

If I try to do the same for a filter list

```
interface FilterList2 {
            "and": {
                "filters": [
                {
                    "or": {
                    "filters": [
                        {
                        "exactMatch": {
                            "terms": string[],
                            "propertyId": string
                        },
                        "type": string
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    "type": string
                }
                ]
            },
            "type": string
    }

    @Function()
    public test3(filter1: FilterList2): FilterList2{
        return filter1
    }
```

I get the following error message:

```
{
 "stdout": "[error] functions-typescript/src/dummy_functions.ts:61:18 - unsupportedType: \"[\n                {\n                    \"or\": {\n                    \"filters\": [\n                        {\n                        \"exactMatch\": {\n                            \"terms\": string[],\n                            \"propertyId\": string\n                        },\n                        \"type\": string\n                        }\n                    ]\n                    },\n                    \"type\": string\n                }\n                ]\" is not a supported type. Please see Functions documentation for a list of supported input and output types.",
 "stderr": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The checks failing is probably because the lexer doesn't like string property names for types or perhaps the `[{defn}]` (TypeScript best practice is to do `{defn}[]`).

This should get your checks to pass:

```js
interface FilterList2 {
    and: {
        filters: {
            or: {
                filters: {
                    exactMatch: {
                        terms: string[]
                        propertyId: string
                    }
                    type: string
                }[]
            }
            type: string
        }[]
        type: string
    }
}
```

However, you will not be able to pass an object set filter to this as an input from the UI (I don't think Workshop supports nested types like `FilterList2` above). You can probably use the `Filters` type from `@foundry/functions-api` instead here.

Comment: Hi, you are right that I cannot use a custom interface to Input/output data. however, the Filters type is not accepted as output variable type. Some idea how to solve this issue? My idea is to modify the filter list in the function. This is why I need it. Thanks!